# Show/Hide divs based on radio button selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hide, show

I've gotten as far as showing a certain div based on the selection of "150" and "3m" but I can't get the div to hide if both of those aren't selected?

Code below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[value="100"], input[value="3m"]').change(function() {
    if ($('input[value="100"]').is(':checked') && $('input[value="3m"]').is(':checked')) {
      $('div').show();
    } else {
      $('div').hide();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>100</label>
<input class="amount" type="radio" name="amount" value="100" />
<label>150</label>
<input class="amount" type="radio" name="amount" value="150" />

<br>
<br>

<label>3</label>
<input class="month" type="radio" name="month" value="3m" />
<label>6</label>
<input class="month" type="radio" name="month" value="6m" />

<div style="display: none;">
  <div class="interest">
    £40
  </div>
  <div class="total-payable">
    £140
  </div>
  <div class="monthly-payment">
    £46.67
  </div>
  <div class="weekly-payment">
    £10.77
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: try with this $('input[value="100"], input[value="3m"],input[value="150"], input[value="6m"]')

Comment: Sorry, I only want it to show if you choose "100" and "3m", I'll amend the question now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently you're only updating the visibility of the `div` elements when the 100 or 3m radio button is changed - you want to update the visibility of the `div` elements on any radio button change by changing your selector:

```
$('input[value="100"], input[value="3m"]')
```

to

```
$('input')
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input').change(function() {
    if ($('input[value="100"]').is(':checked') && $('input[value="3m"]').is(':checked')) {
      $('div').show();
    }
    else {
      $('div').hide();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>100</label>
<input class="amount" type="radio" name="amount" value="100" />
<label>150</label>
<input class="amount" type="radio" name="amount" value="150" />

<br><br>

<label>3</label>
<input class="month" type="radio" name="month" value="3m" />
<label>6</label>
<input class="month" type="radio" name="month" value="6m" />

<div style="display: none;">
<div class="interest">
£40
</div>
<div class="total-payable">
£140
</div>
<div class="monthly-payment">
£46.67
</div>
<div class="weekly-payment">
£10.77
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks so much!

Comment: Can I ask how to then add the function to show the next div (.d21) if "150" and "3m" is chosen?

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gqf2o2mm/5/

Comment: @user3181828 sure - much the same way with the selector and the `.d21` class to your div: https://jsfiddle.net/gqf2o2mm/6/

Comment: @user3181828 The `.d21` div is inside the `.d11` div, which is hidden. You'll have to unhide `.d11` to show `.d21` or move `.d21` outside of the `.d11` div: https://jsfiddle.net/xyhjucs7/1/

Answer (score 2):

For radio buttons, the change event is only triggered when the button gets checked, not when it gets unchecked.

A possible solution is to bind the change event to all (involved) inputs.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input').change(function() {
    if ($('input[value="100"]').is(':checked') && $('input[value="3m"]').is(':checked')) {
      $('div').show();
    }
    else {
      $('div').hide();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>100</label>
<input class="amount" type="radio" name="amount" value="100" />
<label>150</label>
<input class="amount" type="radio" name="amount" value="150" />

<br><br>

<label>3</label>
<input class="month" type="radio" name="month" value="3m" />
<label>6</label>
<input class="month" type="radio" name="month" value="6m" />

<div style="display: none;">
<div class="interest">
£40
</div>
<div class="total-payable">
£140
</div>
<div class="monthly-payment">
£46.67
</div>
<div class="weekly-payment">
£10.77
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can I ask how to then add the function to show the next div (.d21) if "150" and "3m" is chosen? fiddle: jsfiddle.net/gqf2o2mm/5

Comment: Sorry, I sent the wrong link: jsfiddle.net/xyhjucs7

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like the following using the `filter` function and the `:checked` selector:

```js
// wrap in closure
$(function() {
  // store these in variables for better performance
  var month = $('.month'),
      amount = $('.amount'),
      toggleDiv = $('#toggle-div'); // give top level div to show an id rather than toggling all divs
  
  // use common class on radios you want to bind the event to
  $('.radio').on('change', function() {
      if (amount.filter(':checked').val() == 100 && month.filter(':checked').val() === "3m") {
         toggleDiv.show();
      } else {
         toggleDiv.hide();
      }
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>100</label>
<input class="amount radio" type="radio" name="amount" value="100" />
<label>150</label>
<input class="amount radio" type="radio" name="amount" value="150" />

<br>
<br>

<label>3</label>
<input class="month radio" type="radio" name="month" value="3m" />
<label>6</label>
<input class="month radio" type="radio" name="month" value="6m" />

<div id="toggle-div" style="display: none;">
  <div class="interest">
    £40
  </div>
  <div class="total-payable">
    £140
  </div>
  <div class="monthly-payment">
    £46.67
  </div>
  <div class="weekly-payment">
    £10.77
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put all the radio buttons id or name to do the functionality

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>100</label>
<input class="amount" type="radio" name="amount" value="100" id="100rad"/>
<label>150</label>
<input class="amount" type="radio" id="150rad"name="amount" value="150" />

<br><br>

<label>3</label>
<input class="month" type="radio" id="3mrad" name="month" value="3m" />
<label>6</label>
<input class="month" type="radio" name="month" id="6mrad" value="6m" />

<div style="display: none;">
<div class="interest">
£40
</div>
<div class="total-payable">
£140
</div>
<div class="monthly-payment">
£46.67
</div>
<div class="weekly-payment">
£10.77
</div>
</div>
```

js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#3mrad, #150rad,#100rad,#6mrad').change(function() {
    if ($('#150rad').is(':checked') && $('#3mrad').is(':checked')) {
      $('div').show();
    }
    else {
      $('div').hide();
    }
  });
});
```

check the fiddle and let me know that it is what you required or not

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fNPvf/30868/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input[type='button']").click(function(){
        var radioValue = $("input[name='gender']:checked").val();
        if(radioValue){
            alert("Your are a - " + radioValue);
        }
    });
   if(radioValue=='male'){
     $("#divMale").show();
     $("#divFemale").hide();
   } 
   else{
     $("#divMale").hide();
     $("#divFemale").show();
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following javascript code instead. . .set change listener on `input[name="month"], input[name="amount"]`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[name="month"], input[name="amount"]').change(function() {
  console.log("haha")
    if ($('input[value="100"]').is(':checked') && $('input[value="3m"]').is(':checked')) {
      $('div').show();
    }
    else {
      $('div').hide();
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using bootstrap css, you can even make the code much more portable.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input.rbtoggle').change(function () {
        $('div.dvtoggle').toggleClass('d-none');
    });
});
```

where 'rbtoggle' is just a class your radio buttons share, while 'dvtoggle' is a class the div to show or hide uses.

If you want the div hidden initially, add the class 'd-none' to it. E.g

```
<div class'dvtoggle d-none'>
    <!-- other html goes here -->
</div>
```